# How to detect interrupt handle routine of a device driver?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm using Linux platform to program in embedded device.

Is there any way that a kernel module can detect the interrupt handler routine of an another device driver module?

Like for example, I have a kernel module(.ko), then I want this kernel module detect if a particular device driver execute its interrupt handle routine?

Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to modify the device driver to allow your module to register a callback, which the device driver calls during its interrupt routine or similar.

Comment: You mean the interrupt routine of the device driver will call the callback function?

Comment: That's one possibility, but it depends on what you need to do.  A better design might be to have the interrupt routine schedule your callback through a work queue, athough there will be higher latency in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option you can give it a try is: Interrupt Sharing.
You can use the same interrupt in both drivers's request_irq() with appropriate arguments.

Comment: Flag : `SA_SHIRQ`, unsure dev_id is NOT NULL.